# NSData to Data swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

```
var dataFile: NSData = NSMutableData.init(data: wav.subdataWithRange(NSRange.init(location: currentByte, length: wavDataSize)))
```

How to me convert this code to using `Data` with Swift 3? Or how to parse`NSRange` to `Range`

Comment: Check this.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data

Answer (score 11):

## Separating `Data` into smaller `Data` instances

### Assumptions

This answer is the Swift 3 & 4 equivalent of the code in the question. It will produce the same result, `dataFile`, given the same input values: `wav`, `currentByte` and `wavDataSize`  assuming none of the surrounding code changes.

I did not make assumptions about what the variables: `wav`, `dataFile`, `currentByte` or `wavDataSize` mean. To avoid the variable names implying things not stated in the question, I will use the following names instead: `sourceData`, `subdata`, `rangeStartByte` and `subdataLength`. I assume the code (not shown in the question) surrounding this would assure that `rangeStartByte` and `subdataLength` were in a valid range to avoid an error.

### Converting NSRange to Range<Int>

The Swift 2 implementation from the question uses an `NSRange` defined by a start point and a length like this:

```
NSRange.init(location: rangeStartByte, length: subdataLength)
```

The Swift 3 & 4 implementation I propose creates an equivalent `Range<Int>` defined by a start point and end point like this:

```
rangeStartByte ..< (rangeStartByte + subdataLength)
```

I converted an app from Swift 2.2 to 3 which used similar code to upload a photo in smaller chunks. During conversion we missed this nuance and used the Swift 2 implementation's length in place of the Swift 3 & 4 implementation's end point. This caused a defect that was tricky to resolve. The first iteration succeeded but subsequent iterations failed.

Another answer implements the issue I just described as the solution. It uses `subdataLength` from the length of the Swift 2 range as the end point of the Swift 3 & 4 range. This will produce the same result in the special case where currentByte is 0 and `subdataLength` is <= the length of the NSData instance (which is why the first iteration succeeded in the issue I described). That assumption was not explicitly stated in the question and yields a less flexible solution for others.

### Swift 3 & 4 equivalent

```
var subdata = sourceData.subdata(in: rangeStartByte ..< (rangeStartByte + subdataLength))
```

### Swift 2.2

(code from question with updated variable names)

```
var subdata: NSData = NSMutableData.init(data: sourceData.subdataWithRange(NSRange.init(location: rangeStartByte, length: subdataLength)))
```

## Runnable sample code

I've included sample code you can run in a playground demonstrating how this line of code could be used to separate a `Data` instance into smaller `Data` instances. The source `Data` instance is created from a string `"ABCDEFGHIJKL"`. This instance is separated into smaller `Data` instances of length 5.

### Swift 3 & 4 with context

```
import UIKit

var sourceString = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
let sourceData = sourceString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!  // sourceData is equivalent to "wav" from question

var rangeStartByte = 0  // rangeStartByte is equivalent to "currentByte" from question
let maxSubdataLength = 5
let dataLength = sourceString.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
precondition(maxSubdataLength <= dataLength, "maxSubdataLength must be <= to dataLength")

while rangeStartByte < dataLength {
    // subdataLength is equivalent to "wavDataSize" from question
    let subdataLength = min(maxSubdataLength, dataLength - rangeStartByte)

    // subdata is equivalent to "dataFile" from question
    let subdata = Data(sourceData.subdata(in: rangeStartByte ..< (rangeStartByte + subdataLength)))

    let subdataString = String(data: subdata, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
    print("'\(subdataString)'")
    rangeStartByte += subdataLength
}
```

The result is:

```
'ABCDE'
'FGHIJ'
'KL'
```

### Swift 2.2 with context

```
import UIKit

var sourceString = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
let sourceData = sourceString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!  // sourceData is equivalent to "wav" from question

var rangeStartByte = 0  // rangeStartByte is equivalent to "currentByte" from question
let maxSubdataLength = 5
let dataLength = sourceString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
precondition(maxSubdataLength <= dataLength, "maxSubdataLength must be <= to dataLength")

while rangeStartByte < dataLength {
    // subdataLength is equivalent to "wavDataSize" from question
    let subdataLength = min(maxSubdataLength, dataLength - rangeStartByte)

    // subdata is equivalent to "dataFile" from question
    let subdata: NSData = NSMutableData.init(data: sourceData.subdataWithRange(NSRange.init(location: rangeStartByte, length: subdataLength)))

    let subdataString = String(data: subdata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? ""
    print("'\(subdataString)'")
    rangeStartByte += subdataLength
}
```

The result is:

```
'ABCDE'
'FGHIJ'
'KL'
```

### Swift 3 & 4 using NSRange

pedrouan's answer uses NSRange like this:

```
var subdata: Data = Data(sourceData.subdata(with: NSRange(location: rangeStartByte, length: subdataLength)))
```

I could not get this to compile initially so I disregarded it. Now I realize that it works if `sourceData` is declared or cast at `NSData` and not `Data`

If you want to run this approach within the "Swift 3 & 4 with context" sample code above, replace the corresponding code in that sample with this:

```
// subdata is equivalent to "dataFile" from question
let sourceNSData = sourceData as NSData
let subdata = sourceNSData.subdata(with: NSRange(location: rangeStartByte, length: subdataLength))
```

I'm trying not to use "NS" classes like NSRange where possible so I favored the solution using a Swift Range.

Comment: your code crashing with: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'` due to range exceeding data length.

Comment: @MaxPotapov, the code in my answer yields the same result as the code in the question given the same source Data, currentByte, and wavDataSize. This includes out of range errors.  I think we have different assumptions about the question. I updated my answer to include my assumptions. I believe my answer is valid and will be helpful to many developers encountering the same scenario I did.  Your answer crashes also depending on the inputs but it crashes on different input combinations than the code in the question. It is not equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Some 'little' changes in **Swift 3.0**

```
var dataFile: Data = Data(wav.subdata(with: NSRange(location: currentByte, length: wavDataSize)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 your code will be like this one:

```
var dataFile = sourceData.subdata(in: currentByte..<currentByte+wavDataSize)
```

Comment: Checked you link in playground and crashed with exception. See my comment in answer.

Comment: This answer is not equivalent to the code in the question for all combinations of currentByte and wavDataSize. It is only equivalent when currentByte is 0 and wavDataSize is <= the source Data length. That was not a stated assumption. You noted my answer crashed when you didn’t expect it. That was likely because of assumptions outside of the question. I updated my answer to reflect my assumptions. It is equivalent to the question code for all combinations of currentByte and wavDataSize including when it crashes due to out of bounds errors. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Regards,

Comment: @Peacemoon, I think you and I are interpreting the question the same way which is more generic. Please see the added explanation in my answer. Thank You.